# Form input attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, form-for

i work on my Ruby on Rails application and i'm new to Rails.
I use "form_for tag".`enter code here`

```
 <%= f.label :password %>
  <%= f.password_field :password%>
```

I need to add "onkeyup"attribute  to my input field so it looks like this in produced HTML:

```
<input  type="password" id="password" onkeyup="checkPassword(this);" />;
```

How do i do it in Rails 3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
<%= f.password_field :password, :onkeyup => "checkPassword(this);" %>
```